# Power operator in Chisel

Tags: scala, chisel, register-transfer-level

I am trying to find an equivalent of Verilog power operator ** in Chisel. I went through [Chisel Cheat sheet](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/chisel-cheatsheet.pdf) and [tutorial](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki/) but I did not find what I was looking for. After going through designs written in Chisel, I found that **log2xx** functions are popular choice while the power operator is never used. Of course I can always use the shift operator to get power of 2 but I was hoping that there is general power operator in Chisel. I tried to use scala's math functions to the job but I got compilation error.

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to create hardware that can compute an exponent or are you trying to calculate a constant or bitwidth?

Comment: I am trying to calculate bitwidth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to calculate a bitwidth which is calculated at *elaboration time* (ie. when Scala is elaborating the hardware graph), we can use Scala functions. Scala only provides a [power function for Doubles](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/index.html#pow(x:Double,y:Double):Double), but that works just fine for this case. Try `math.pow(base, exp).toInt`, note that `base` and `exp` can both be Ints and Scala will automatically convert them to Doubles for the function call. You simply need to convert the resulting Double to an Int for use as a bitwidth.